# Search all TABLE columns in Kohana 3.2

Tags: database, search, kohana

I have a Contacts DB Table with several columns such as First Name, Last Name, Telephone. Mobile etc.

I also have a search field with text input and select input when I must specify Column name to search in to.
For example, search "Tom" in "First Name" gives me a list of contacts which names contain name "Tom".

Can I make it simple? I don want to specify Column name, just want search in all Columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make 4 `OR WHERE` statements then:

```
DB::select()->from('your_table')->where('First Name', '=', $val)->or_where('Last Name', '=', $val)->or_where('Telephone', '=', $val)->or_where('Mobile ', '=', $val)->execute();
```